# Randomise Author names in Latex

Tags: random, latex

I use latex to write papers and am often annoyed by the process of working out the order that names should appear in the list of authors - it causes too may arguments early on, just when you don't need them.

I'd like to know if there is a latex feature/snippit, they will let me enter the authors and their details, but randomise the order every time the latex is compiled. So my name might be first on one version, and then when I recompile, it would be someone else's name first.

how would I start?

Comment: Just sort them alphabetically and have a note that explicitly states this. This will avoid arguments, and tough luck, Zumberg!

Comment: I should have clarified...  I meant that with a randomization function you would have the names there but not in any established order.  The idea being that there was no set ideas when we sit down at the end and have a grown up conversation about the ordering.   I wasn't planning on just having randomly names on the final submission :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [PerlTex](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb28-3/tb90mertz.pdf). By embedding some Perl code within your LaTex document you can easily randomize author names. [This link](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-07/msg00441.html) shows how to do it. I haven't tested if the code shown there actually works, but the principle should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

There's some random number things in the probsoln package. Here's something that might get you started:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{probsoln}
\PSNrandseed{\time}
\begin{document}
\doforrandN{3}{\who}{Fred,Barry,Joe}{ 
\who
}
\end{document}
```

Note the seed only seems to change once per minute.

Answer (score 0):

The `pgfmath` package allows you to create some list data structures.  Then you can implement a knuth shuffle on them.  See [this post on pgf-users from 2009](http://old.nabble.com/Random-permutation-of-a-list-td23374057.html).

`pgfmath` is part of `tikz` but works independently of it.

Comment: BTW you can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a bad idea, as the user could simply recompile
until he likes the order.  The order should be randomized only once,
with randomness verified by all involved.

Get everyone together, then draw lots, or use some quick script like this:

```
(defun random-order (&rest items)
  (when items
    (let ((this (elt (random (length items)) items)))
      (cons this
            (random-order (remove this items
                                  :test #'equal))))))

(random-order "Gimme Gimme" "Me First" "Allim Portant")
```

(You can use whatever language you want, of course.)